# Java for squid3 url_rewrite_program

Tags: java, squid

I am trying to start squid with a Java program as url_rewrite_program. But whenever I start the server it fails. This command worked:

> url_rewrite_program /home/seed/myprog.pl

but when I put my Java program on it, it fails. Does anybody knows if there is a special syntax. I tried: ",', nothing, with the java command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a lot on the internet and found people having the same problem. Mostly, they though it was a problem with their java code our squid support and they end-up using python. So I decided to let the solution I found. Squid was not finding the java command. No " or ' was necessary. just a complete path on everything:

> /usr/bin/java -jar ...